# Database design with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: database, database-design, asp.net-identity

As we all know that we may extend the profile information based on ASP.NET Identity to another table or include it to the default table (`ASPNetUsers`).

Supposingly i only have two field to be fill in during registration (username and email) only, but upon completing registration, user may or may not opt to fill in extra profile information (such as sex, birthdate, real name etc).

I have two options in my mind but not sure which is the more appropriate way.

1. All profile information (username, email, sex, birthdate, real name) include in the default identity `ASPNetUsers` table.
2. Required registration information(username and email) for default identity `ASPNetUsers` table, while the extra profile information is in another table which is linked to the default identity `ASPNetUsers` table.

Or is there any better option? Hope that we may gain something new in this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with option 2. As the profile is likely to change. More over if I need to take out the identity to some other server it is easy to take them there. or later to extend to federated identity(well.. this can act both ways due to sync issues).

Comment: Well, you have a point here. But what if some of the profile information (First Name and Last Name) is required during registration? Still appropriate with option 2? (First Name last name, username and email in the default table) and other profile information to another table?

Comment: Things used when you need to login. This can be 3 things max 1) Password 2) Email or 3)Username. This can remain in one. Rest of the details can go to profile.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add custom properties as a Claim on user. Then in your views access these claims from ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.

Claims on principal are available in the cookie, so no extra DB hits required.

I think this is the best and most performant solution

[How to user claims in asp.net identity](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.ch/2013/12/using-claims-in-aspnet-identity.html)

Comment: I am not sure how this answers the question. The question was on data storage. But your answer is on using the data from data storage.

Comment: The claims will be stored in a seperated table (AspNetUserClaims) linked with user. To save custom fields has already been implemented with claims. Thus would also be the question of how do I save my data cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a project where there are several solutions using the same Authentication/Authorization project. 
The authentication project is the only one that uses tables AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, ...
By the other hand, other projects have their own "Users" table with the extra information that each one need.
If one project need "BirthDate" and other project needs "Sex", we are not going to put both in the common 
authentication tables, giving to all projects extra information that isn't useful for each one.

Working that way we are also giving the "Single responsability" of Authentication and Authorization to
one project, avoiding the code repeating.

That's why I think that the second option is more scalable and maintainable.